# "bufalign" and "bufoffset" integers in ttcp source code

Tags: c

There is a small and fairly old utility named *ttcp*(Test TCP) which is used for TCP and UDP bandwidth testing. Source code can be found [here](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/sgi/src/ttcp/ttcp.c). In this source code there are integer type variables `bufalign` and `bufoffset` with default values of 16384 and 0 bytes accordingly. Those two variables are used for creating another variable named `buf`:

```
if (bufalign != 0)
        buf +=(bufalign - ((int)buf % bufalign) + bufoffset) % bufalign;
```

If I understand correctly, this `buf` is later used for actually sending the data with `write()` and `sendto()` system calls. However, while the math in code snippet above is easy and I understand that `bufalign` and `bufoffset` variables are related to memory allocation, I do not understand why they are needed in *ttcp* source code?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you're wondering why they are variables instead of being static constants (ie `static const int bufalign = ...`, etc) or just hard-coded unnamed magic numbers. Doing a quick search on the page, the only place they're assigned is in their declaration statements or while doing command line argument processing.

Since it is possible to specify command line arguments that change their values, I'm guessing that's "why they are needed in the source code".

--EDIT--

The line of code `buf +=(bufalign - ((int)buf % bufalign) + bufoffset) % bufalign;` is just pointer arithmetic to ensure that the memory address `buf` points to is aligned to a specific multiple. The memory address of `buf` is incremented so that it is equal to the next memory location that is a multiple of `bufalign` (so that `buf` starts at a memory address that is a multiple of 16k by default), with an additional offset of `bufoffset`.

You are correct in your assumption of how buf is used later. However, the pointer arithmetic with bufalign and bufoffset is unnecessary and should be removed. The source code is pretty old style C - my best guess is that this line of code in question was needed on whatever platform(s) this program was originally designed for.

I also don't see anything freeing the memory that was allocated for buf, which is a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm wondering why those two variables are needed in the first place. I fully understand the `buflen` variable which defines the amount of data in TCP segment(aka packet) and is also used for creating the `buf` variable in `buf = (char *)malloc(buflen+bufalign)`. However, I don't understand what is the purpose of this calculation: `buf +=(bufalign - ((int)buf % bufalign) + bufoffset) % bufalign` ..and in overall, what is the purpose of `bufalign` and `bufoffset`.